# Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\\ApiCore\\Serializer' not found in /mnt/e/htdocs/firestore-test/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, ubuntu, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having troubles with connecting to my firestore and read data from it.

HERE IS THE Error that occurred:

> [Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\ApiCore\Serializer' not found in /mnt/e/htdocs/firestore-test/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93 ]

Composer:

[image: Composer]

FIRESTORE DATABASE:

[image: FIRESTORE DATABASE]

HERE IS MY CODE.

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$firestore = new FirestoreClient();

$document01 = $firestore->collection("Book")->document("

m4ZEpHNcZN7NQW6Hn2Lg");

$document01Snap = $document01->snapshot(); 

echo $document01Snap->exists() ? "EXISTS" : "DOES NOT EXIST -_-";
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump($document01Snap->data());
echo PHP_EOL;
```